# how to extract every data point of a minute in a dataset?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have a dataset which contains every minute data for one month. So, how do I get every data-point for a particular minute?

My Pandas Dataframe looks some thing like this:

> 1. 2018-06-01 08:00:00
> 2. 2018-06-01 08:01:00
> 3. 2018-06-01 08:02:00
> 4. ............
> 5. ............
> 6. ............
> 7. 2018-06-30 23:57:00
> 8. 2018-06-30 23:58:00
> 9. 2018-06-30 23:59:00

Example: Let's say I want to get every data point for **08:03:00**. So there will be **30** instances of that value in the whole month. So, how do I get all the values for that minute?

If anyone has worked on something like this, it would be really helpful.

**Edit:** My dataframe is like this

[image: Dataframe description]

Comment: [How to create minmal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Ambient T and Ambient RH. I have added the image of my dataframe. Sorry for not following the norms and for the bad post.

Comment: It's difficult to reproduce the problem if you don't provide it as text. See my solution with limited data. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create `DatetimeIndex` and then use [`DataFrame.at_time`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.at_time.html):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Ambient': [1,5,6]},
                   index= ['2018-06-01 08:00:00','2018-06-01 08:01:00','2018-06-01 08:01:00'])
print (df)
                     Ambient
2018-06-01 08:00:00        1
2018-06-01 08:01:00        5
2018-06-01 08:01:00        6

#if necessary
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index)

df1 = df.at_time('08:01:00')
print (df1)
                     Ambient
2018-06-01 08:01:00        5
2018-06-01 08:01:00        6
```

Comment: This is the one I was searching for, thanks, got to know this `at_time`

Answer (score 2):

Here's one solution:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'datetime':['2018-06-01 08:00:00', '2018-06-01 08:01:00', '2018-06-01 08:01:00']})

# Convert datetime column into `pandas datetime`
df['datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['datetime'])

# Create a new column with only time
df['tme'] = df['datetime'].dt.time

# This is a time for which you have to fetch the data
t = pd.to_datetime('08:01:00').time()

print(df[df['tme']==t])
```

Output:

```
    datetime             tme
1   2018-06-01 08:01:00  08:01:00
2   2018-06-01 08:01:00  08:01:00
```

Comment: Also, for this to work, will need to reset the index based on dataframe shown in question.

Comment: thanks, but I found the answer by @jezrael  to be more helpful, hence I approved that.